# gitflow maven plugin - develop version after hotfix finish

Tags: maven, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I use gitflow maven plugin in java-maven project.
After I run the goal hotfix-finish, the hotfix branch merged sucssfully to master and develop.
The version in master and develop is the same (in develop it is SANPSHOT).
I accept the version in develop will be the next version + SNAPSHOT. 
Who can I configure the plugin to upgrade the version in develop, and what will happen with feature branches that are open?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this:
Increment major version in develop branch in each release by using versionDigitToIncrement, and then use the minor versions for hotfixes

Enjoy!